# Make sense of this unwanted bootstrap behavior with regards to positioning?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay so on my website I have two btn-lg.  There is one button at the top of the page with a large form beneath it( with display set to none initially).  Then the other btn-lg is below that with another large form beneath it (display also initially set to none).  On click the buttons reveal their respective forms.

My dilemma is I want to center the buttons on the page and display the forms as they are now. I can get the buttons centered by putting a div with a class of col-xs-12 around it, and setting the text-align property of the div to center.

The problem with this is that when I toggle the form using a button click, the forms are smushed up against the right side of the page, looking nothing like they are supposed to!  This is only a problem after adding the div around both buttons.

I am only putting the div around each button, not around the form. The form is made of form-group's that are all very similar to this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputInsured" class="col-lg-2 control-label"> Name of insured(s)</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="inputInsured" name="name" placeholder="" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

The only positioning given to the form is the class of col-lg-10 and col-lg-2 you see in this form-group. (all of them have that).

So does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: You should include a complete working example of your code, your current example does not include any buttons etc: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out the problem.  My col-xs-12 classes were not contained within a row.  Columns need rows or you will run into problems. This tutorial explained it nicely http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php